# No Compiled Files in OSGi Jar Exported by Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi

When I export the jar with plan "Export deployable plug-ins and fragments" tool; the exported jar does not contain any compiled classes.

In the Eclipse ide, all Java files are compiled without error and when I run the OSGi project directly from Eclipse, it executes successfully.

What should I do? How can I see the error, log etc?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I found it. Unfortunately my build.properties file had been broken. Now it is working.

Comment: Are you using Java 9 or 10? PDE Build has problem with these versions.

Comment: Thanks @greg-449. I found the problem. source line had been deleted from build.properties file. How stupid i am.

Comment: Are you creating a server side project? If yes I would not recommend using the PDE to develop it. It is much simpler to use maven with the bnd-maven-plugin.